# Execute Javascript in Sinatra

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript, sinatra

I searched a lot but I can't seem to find a clear answer about how to execute javascript code via Sinatra, it symply renders the code as html for me. Here is what I tried so far :

```
require 'sinatra'

set :public_folder, 'public'

class Dashboard < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    send_file File.join(settings.public_folder, 'javascripts/index.js') # renders code as html
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>' # nothing
    '<script>alert("Hello, world !")</script>' # works correctly
  end
end
```

Comment: render js: '<script type="text/javacript" >alert("q");</script>' try pls

Comment: "wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..4)", also just '<script>alert("hello")</script>' is working, but I'm really trying to load a script from a file here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, the path in src must be so :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/index.js"></script>
```